# Dynamic Function Analysis

Tags: reverse-engineering, taxonomy

I found this program that appears to assist with locating when a function is called in a program. It seems quite handy and I am wondering if there is more out there like it.
http://split-code.com/cda.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0UXR861WYM

What exactly would this program be classified as? Are there other programs similar? Is this widely used and I'm just a fool?

Comment: I'd just call this a specialized debugger I think.

Answer (score 1):

As the link you provided states, this tool is a

> dynamic code analysis process instrumentation tool

- ***Dynamic*** It is used to inspect programs at runtime.
- ***Code analysis*** It provides information about the code executing (?)
- ***Process*** It analysis code running in a process (specifically, a 32-bit x86 process under *Windows*)
- ***[Instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_(computer_programming))*** This tool uses debugging techniques to allow automatic tracing (into every inter-modular function call) and profiling. It also allows for [PIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_(computer_program)) like (although probably not as neatly implemented) callbacks.

I must mention that the author using *analysis* is somewhat inaccurate. The software (as far as I understand it) does not analyses code, it only provides inter-modular and intra-modular calls information from runtime. [IDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Disassembler), on the other hand, is a real *analysis* tool, because it provides information like `x-refs` and `string view`, which can only be given via in depth analysis.

There is no 'short name' for this specific type of program. This program will be classified as some sort of *Instrumentational* software, .

Comment: Analysis is any process that takes a program and produces facts about that program.  Producing A-calls-B from a program is thus an analysis.  You might decide that only *static* "analyses" are analyses, but in fact a runtime analysis is trivially (in theory) turned into a static analysis by simply having the static analyzer simply use an interpreter to simulate program execution.

Comment: @IraBaxter Although you're theoretically correct, I'd argue that the given program still shouldn't be considered an "analyzer". First, it doesn't produce facts without an environment (it really doesn't have an in-base interpreter). Secondly, the criteria (produces facts about...) is loosely define. Generally, any execution of a program would produce facts about it (otherwise it's meaningless), and we certainly don't want to call everything in the computer an "analyzer" for every program running. The "analyzer" term is saved for real analyzers, like IDA or ReSharper (for code).

Comment: I consider an analysis to be *any* function of the program source text, except the actual output of the program (and we might argue about; it is useful to ask, "what will this program produce?").